# NotSupported result when LaunchQuerySupportType is UriForResults

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a UWP app in which I've defined a custom protocol. I'm currently launching that app via another app using the `LaunchUriForResultsAsync` and receiving a the expected response without a problem:

```
var options = new LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = TARGET_PACKAGE;
var launchResults = await Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(new Uri($"myprotocol:?b={cids}"), options);
```

However, when I want to query to see if I have an app installed that can handle `myprotocol:` I'm not getting the result I expect.

The first method, using `LaunchQuerySupportType.Uri` returns `Supported` as expected:

```
var queryResult = await Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync(new Uri("myprotocol:"), LaunchQuerySupportType.Uri, TARGET_PACKAGE);
```

When using `LaunchQuerySupportType.UriForResults` I get `NotSupported` returned.

```
var queryResult = await Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync(new Uri("myprotocol:"), LaunchQuerySupportType.UriForResults, TARGET_PACKAGE);
```

Is there a flag I'm missing in the manifest of my app that implements the custom protocol? What am I missing here?

(see [QueryUriSupportAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer typically appears ONLY after posting the question :p

There is a `ReturnResults` attribute that is not exposed in the GUI for the Package.appxmanifest when setting up the protocol

The ReturnResults attribute in the protocol extension accepts one of these values:

- **optional**—The app can be launched for results by using the `LaunchUriForResultsAsync` method, or not for results by using `LaunchUriAsync`. When you use **optional**, the launched app must determine whether it was launched for results. It can do that by checking the `OnActivated` event argument. If the argument's `IActivatedEventArgs.Kind` property returns `ActivationKind.ProtocolForResults`, or if the type of the event argument is `ProtocolActivatedEventArgs`, the app was launched via `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`.
- **always**—The app can be launched only for results; that is, it can respond only to `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`.
- **none**—The app cannot be launched for results; it can respond only to `LaunchUriAsync`.

(see [How to launch an app for results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn997827.aspx))